# indefinite articles before adjectives

Tags: punctuation, articles

Is this sentence grammatically and lexically correct?

'For me, foreign language is the stem of a teaching and translating career'

Comment: 'For me, proficiency in a foreign language is a prerequisite for a career in either teaching or translating.'

Comment: Thank you very much! Does this sound natural : what attracts me most in the translating is a fertile soil for the intellectual growth it provides me with.

Comment: _what attracts me most to translating is the fertile soil it provides for intellectual growth_.

Comment: Sadly, a common example of a ground metaphor is 'bogged down' or 'stuck'.

Comment: Could you suggest an equivalent expression?

Comment: Sorry, I was attempting a pun. 'Fertile ground' is fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the midwest of the United States, we might replace "stem" with the word "bedrock" or "foundation."  But we might also change the whole thing around a bit and say something like...

I believe that the knowledge of a foreign language is an absolute necessity for a career in language teaching and translation.

However, this changes the entire sentence from a statement to an assertion.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The sentence doesn't clearly convey the idea you wish to express.  You should define foreign language--speaking or knowing one?  Also, "stem" is not what we would use.  Foundation has been suggested but I would choose "basis."

"For me, speaking a foreign language is the basis for a teaching and translating career."